# File ownership for mediawiki and semantic media wiki

Tags: mediawiki, ownership

I installed mediawiki & semantic mediawiki on a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.

### Questions

- Should the `www-data` user own every file of mediawiki? Is it better to let `root` own the files?
- Should I run composer with the `www-data` user? I mean `sudo -u www-data composer update --nodev`? When I run composer with root, composer says that is bad.

### Installation of Mediawiki

1. Install semantic, following https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Debian_or_Ubuntu
2. `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/mediawiki/images/` for uploading images and other files.
3. Now everything in `/var/lib/mediawiki` is owned by `root:root`, except for the `images/` folder.
4. Set up short url by modifying `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/000-default.conf` and follow the guide at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

### Installation of Semantic Mediawiki

1. `sudo apt-get install composer`
2. Create `/var/lib/mediawiki/composer.local.json` with the following content:

```json
{
    "require":{
        "mediawiki/semantic-mediaw-wiki": "~3.2"
    }
}
```

as described in https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Installation/Quick_guide

3. `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/mediawiki`
4. While the guide asked me to run `composer update --nodev`, I run the command with the `www-data` user and within the `/var/lib/mediawiki` folder:

```bash
cd /var/lib/mediawiki && sudo -u www-data composer update --nodev
```

5. `sudo -u www-data php maintenance/update.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, and something I *still* wonder if I'm doing the "right way" or the best way. But to attempt to give you two potential answers to your questions:

> Should the www-data user own every file of mediawiki? Is it better to let root own the files?

It seems fine either way. The www-data user only needs to be able to *write* to `images` and `cache`, though. I think it's considered best practice to put `cache` outside your web root and set its path with [`$wgCacheDirectory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheDirectory) anyway.

To avoid having to run any maintenance tasks as root, and to prevent the web server user itself from being able to write to places where it doesn't need to, I have a dedicated group for this, let's call it "adm".

I would use an account in this group (say, my personal account) for doing all that "maintenance stuff" like editing `LocalSettings.php` and running scripts from the `maintenance` directory. So the setup for a new MediaWiki installation might look something like this:

```bash
# assuming Debian/Ubuntu
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/w      # you used /var/lib/mediawiki here
sudo mkdir g+w w                # not sure if this is always necessary
sudo setfacl -m g:adm:rwx w     # allow 'adm' group to read/write
sudo setfacl -d -m g:adm:rwx w  # make above default for new files/dirs

cd w
curl https://latest.mediawiki.release | tar xvf - --strip-components=1
sudo setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX cache images
sudo setfacl -R -d -m g:www-data:rwX cache images
```

And yes, I would probably [verify the signatures](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download#Signature_downloads) in real life. And yes, sometimes even *I* wonder if it needs to be that complicated, and maybe there is something more straightforward that could be done with the ACLs. Suggestions/edits welcome, obviously.

> Should I run composer with the www-data user? I mean `sudo -u www-data composer update --nodev`? When I run composer with root, composer says that is bad.

Having set things up as above, I would run `composer` as somebody in the "adm" group.